# cannot fetch from local nodejs server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

i apparently try to fetch data from local nodejs server but got weird error. this is simple server with express

```
let express = require('express')
let server = express()
server.listen(3100)
server.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.send("hello") })
```

and this is the code in my react. i only use it in useEffect

```
fetch('http://localhost:3100/', {
        headers: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin',
        method: "GET"
    })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

and i got this error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The provided value is not of type '(sequence<sequence<ByteString>> or record<ByteString, ByteString>)'
```

i have no idea why is this happening, i look around the internet but still didnt get the solution. thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: `headers` is an object and moreover `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should done by the `server` side. `headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json', etc...}`

Comment: This is a strange error indeed but sometimes node debugging is messy and the errors seem irrelevant. A relevant error might be with cross-origin, as I am assuming you run your 'fetch' app on a different local port and need cors enabled. You need to add server.use(cors()); to your node app to enable cross-origin requests

Comment: @StavrosAngelis — It's a browser side error, nothing to do with Node.

Comment: True but if the server API doesn't allow cross-origin requests the 'fetch' request will also fail so that also needs fixing.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because the value of `headers` cannot be a string.

It should be a plain object (or a `Headers` instance) where each property is a header name and the associated value is the header value. ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch))

```
headers: {
    "X-Example-Request-Header": "Example value"
}
```

---

In this particular case, you shouldn't be setting `headers` at all. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a **response** header, not a request header. Adding it to the request can only cause problems.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35553666/19068) for further reading on that subject and the [`cors` middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) to add CORS permissions to your Express server.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add a header that is not of type `string`, it should be of type `Header`

```
fetch(' URL ... ',
{
method: "GET",
    headers: new Headers({
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
    }),
    body: formData
}
```